# Executing web service methods is slow

Tags: web-services, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I know that first call to web service can take much more time, but next calls takes min. 250ms every time. It is doesn't matter if web service return simple object (string, boolean) or more complex array. (Web service processing time is about 1-5ms for simple object)

Is it normal that calling Webservice take at least 250 ms on Windows Mobile (Motorola MC3190 device)? Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Did you profile the code? Is there a delay in the web service, is the web service reading from a database? 250 ms each time sounds like it is transferring via network at constant speed. Did you try 3G? Wifi?

Comment: I use WiFi to connect to web service, there is no delay on web service. When I call web service from desktop client there is respond in 4-8ms. For me it is looks like WM or .Net processing.